# permissions error: dovecot log

Tags: centos, email, dovecot, exim

I'm trying to install exim + dovecot on my centOS server. And when i tried to run( as root )  it, I am getting the below message:

> Starting Dovecot Imap: Error: Can't write to log directory /var/log: Permission denied
>   Fatal: Invalid configuration in /etc/dovecot.conf

I even tried to set permissions to 777, but that didn't help. Also I had the same problem with dovecot.conf, I solved this by deleting dovecot.conf and creating it again. Would appreciate for any help. My dovecot.conf looks like this:

```
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log

login_greeting = pop3/imap service.

protocol imap {

}

protocol pop3 {

}
pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv

protocol lda {

  postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com

  mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/lda

}

auth default {

  mechanisms = plain login cram-md5 digest-md5

  passdb passwd-file {

  args = /etc/dovecot.passwd

  }

  userdb passwd-file {

  args = /etc/dovecot.passwd

  }

  user = root

  socket listen {

 client {

`}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but I had a similar problem recently so set about fixing it.

I had a server with dovecot apparently running as a non-root user (parent process running as root, but child processes for services running as `mail`). This can sometimes happen if you manage a server with a third-party control panel which configures various services or applications with non-standard permissions.

With no logrotate rule configured for them the server ended up nearly filling its disk, but after deleting the logs and restarting the dovecot service: no incoming mail was being delivered despite the log files being initially created OK! (I didn't need to `touch` the files).

I didn't notice this problem until a test email, sent after the first dovecot restart, didn't arrive. However I subsequently received a message delay notification to my sending test account, containing the dovecot.log error message from the server.

I first ran `ps aux | grep dovecot` to identify the running user - it indicated some processes running as `root` but others running as `mail`.

In the server's `dovecot.conf`, for all of the `service` declarations it also had `user = mail` and `group = mail` lines.

So, I ran (either as root, or using sudo)

`chown mail:mail /var/log/dovecot*.log`

then ran `service dovecot restart`

and emails began to flow again. NB that on this particular machine, dovecot.log only logged service restarts as it was set to verbose logging; all the other info filed into `dovecot-info.log` and `dovecot-debug.log`.

I could see emails arriving and being delivered by tailing the mail log:

`tail -fn 100 /var/log/maillog` (this might be named something like `mail.log` for you).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the message is `can't write to log directory /var/log`  It's not clear from your post whether you changed the permissions on /var/log or on /var/log/dovecot.log.

/var/log is typically owned by root with permissions 755.  dovecot is supposed to be run as root:

```
Normally Dovecot logs everything through its master process, which is running as root.
```

from the dovecot [Local Delivery Agent wiki](http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA).

All of this leads me to suspect you are somehow starting dovecot as some other non-root user.  Please supply info on how exactly you are starting dovecot.  Typically it's done by a system startup script (as root).  Alternately you can try launching dovecot on the command line as root with

```
sudo /usr/sbin/dovecot
```

and see if that works.  That's just for troubleshooting though, you need to launch it automatically via a system startup script.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can keep trying to solve it and I am sure you will, but in such cases when things just go messy, the fastest (not best) way is to:

```
yum remove dovecot
yum install dovecot
```

You're done ;)